# CSS3 transition performance - browser, os and hardware recommendations?

Tags: performance, css, webkit, hardware-acceleration

I am planning a browser based kiosk application that will utilize CSS3 transitions (mainly on opacity) on relatively high resolution (1920x1080px) images.

Doing some preliminary testing on CSS3 transitions I have seen huge differences on rendering performance between Safari and Chrome under OSX 10.7.2 - a bit surprising.

Could anyone give me some recommendations as to OS, browser and hardware suggestions in order to maximize performance?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stripped down Linux with Chromium Daily builds or Trunk, hardware depends on budget

Comment: Would Chromium per definition have better performance than using Chrome under OSX or Win?

Comment: You can strip down Linux into a minimal pair or libs and executables to fire up an graphical display (X server), you cant do that with canned OS, nor its legal. Chromium its always better then Chrome because its the bleeding edge of the development itself, chrome its based upon chromium. I make HTML5 and i can tell you Chromium its better.